# Avoiding Select with Copy and Paste VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to reduce my usage of select. I have been referencing the article below but I am not entirely sure how to implement it in this scenario. To practice I have the working set of code below that I use to copy the value in B1 and paste it down as many rows that are filled in column A. If someone could coach me through how to avoid this bad habit in order to write more effective and efficient code, I would greatly appreciate it!

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

```
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, "B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: This question is asked almost every day now and we have tons on SO!

Comment: What to do when duplicate question is asked  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: Not sure this question is for SO as OP doesn't have an issue with his code, they just want to know a better way to do this. Possible for one of the sister sites where code is reviewed

Comment: @TDJ: also, take a look at [MSDN: Excel VBA reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-excel) and [Chip Pearson's excellent site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of that code can be translated to this:

`Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value = Range("B1").Value`

We're making the `Range` of cells `B1` through `B` and the last row of cells in column `A` (which we get by using `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`) equal to the value in cell `B1`.

[image: img1]

Comment: Maybe next time! ;)

Comment: OP code will stop if there is an empty cell in column A.

Comment: @VincentG From the sounds of it he doesn't have empty cells in column A, but according to his question he wanted to "paste it down as many rows that are filled in column A", which sounds like the typical fill down to last row situation.

Answer (score 6):

Others have provided direct solutions to your code.  But to your question on being "Coached" on how to avoid Select, this is what is happening...

Consider .Select as storing a Reference to whatever it's attached to.

```
Range("B1").Select
```

is saying store a reference to the Range: B1.

```
Selection.Copy
```

is saying use that reference, and call the function Copy

Instead of using the reference, you can access it directly.

```
Range("B1").Copy
```

Now since your copying and pasting you have two different references, your source and your destination.  So you can apply the value directly from source to destination, without invoking copy and paste functions.

```
Range(<DestinationRange>).value = Range(<SourceRange>).value
```

The offset functions are simply saying Start at the Range specified, and move over the specified number of column(s) or row(s), and use this cell as your reference.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
Sub copyPaste()
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope. OP wants the value in B1 down, not the values in column A.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I read the question wrong.  Looks like dwirony already got the answer for him.